# php work with variables

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

as you will see I'm a newbie

I have the following code:

```
while($file = readdir($dir)){
    if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
    $cont++;
        ...
        ...
     }
}
```

and next I want to work with the variable $file but if I do the this:

```
if($file){
    echo"OK";
}else{
       echo"Error";
}
```

I get ther Error message.

How can I work with the $file outside the while cycle??

Thanks

Comment: "`$file` outside the `while`" does not make sense. *Which* file exactly?

Answer (score 3):

$file will be a boolean FALSE value when the loop exits. When readdir hits the end of the directory and has nothing more to read, it returns FALSE, which is assigned to your $file value.

As such, after the while() loop exits, $file will ALWAYS be false. If you want to preserve a particular filename for use outside the loop, you'll have to assign it to some other variable inside the loop:

```
while($file = readdir($dir)) {
   if ( ... ) { }
   $lastfile = $file;
}

...
```

With this, when the while() loop exits, $lastfile will have the filename of the last file returned by readdir.

Answer (score 1):

The `$file` is only existing **inside** the while loop.. Which is pretty obvious. 
Why would you want to use it outside of the loop? In that case anyway you'd just have the LAST `$file`. Possibility would be thus to declare a variable above the while loop, assign it inside the loop and use it after the loop.

```
$fix_file;

while($file = readdir($dir)){
    if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
        $cont++;
        $fix_file = $file;
        break;
     }
}

if ($fix_file)
     echo "OK";
else
     echo "Error";
```

Comment: It exists outside the loop as well. PHP's variable scope is function-level, not block-level. It's just that the while() sets it to false when readdir has nothing more to read.

Answer (score 0):

What do you really want to test about $file - if it has any value at all?  You can check this with the [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) functions.